# Is it possible to seal classes in a jar file?

Tags: java, jar, manifest, sealed

So I know it is possible to seal a package in a jar file by setting the sealed attribute to true but is it possible to do the same with class entries in the manifest?

Will this sealed attribute below work if Boot.class exists or is sealed only meant for packages?

Example:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Name: com/myCompany/randompackage/Boot.class 
Sealed: true
```

Comment: What are you intending to *achieve* by sealing a specific class?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html

Comment: I've read this article and it only shows how to seal a package, I was wondering if it was possible for class entries

Answer (score 9):

It does not make any sense to seal a class. You can seal only a package, because only a package needs protection. There is no need to protect a class, because it is not possible to spread the contents of one class over two files. It is only possible to spread the classes of one package over two JARs.  And sealing means preventing this.  And although it is not the default it is a good idea to make it a default.

**Example**

Alice writes a package called `alice`, which contains two classes `alice.Data` and `alice.Work`. The Data class contains some variables which must not be changed.  Otherwise the code in the Work class might fail.  Alice declares the Data class as package private, because the Work class needs access to the data. Now she puts both classes of the package into the JAR called `alice.jar` and gives the JAR to Bob.

But Bob needs more to be done and asks Mallory to write another class, because Alice works already on something else.  So Mallory writes a package called `mallory` and implements the required class called `mallory.Work`.  But Mallory is envious and wants to discredit Alice and writes another class called `alice.Anger`.  And she puts both classes into the JAR called `mallory.jar` and gives the JAR to Bob.

Bob uses both JARs and runs into trouble with Alice´s code, because the class `alice.Anger` from the `mallory.jar` has package private access to the package `alice` and disrupts the data in `alice.Data`.

If Alice would have sealed her JAR, it would not be possible for Mallory to put a class in the `mallory.jar` which belongs to the package `alice`.  Java would reject this JAR, because there is already another JAR containing the package `alice` and each package must be in only one JAR.